# how can I get parsable output from dnf list installed?

Tags: dnf

`dnf list installed` output is human readable but not very friendly to machine parser.
is there a command allow us get the installed package in json or csv or other parser friendly format? Does dnf have python binding provide nicer interface?

Comment: Do you actually need the dnf-specific information (such as which repository a package came from)? If not, you can cut out the middle man and just ask rpm for the list of installed packages (`rpm -qa` for example)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `rpm` command provides some more flexible options for printing the result. For listing installed packages you can use `rpm --query --all` and format the output using `--queryformat`.

For example to print just names of the packages you can use `rpm -qa --queryformat "%{NAME}\n"`. You can further specify the output in a `printf`-like syntax and you can use `rpm --querytags` to print all available "variables" `rpm` can print about the packages. Check [rpm man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/rpm.8.html) for more information.

Yes, DNF also has Python bindings, documentation is available [here](https://dnf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py-modindex.html) and to get installed packages you can do something like:

```python
import dnf

base = dnf.Base()
base.fill_sack() 
q = base.sack.query() 
list(q.installed())
```

Answer (score 2):

> *Is there a command allow us get the installed package in JSON or CSV or other parser friendly format?*

It might also be possible by using post-processing in example like

```bash
dnf list installed | tail -n +2 | awk -F '[.]' '{ print $1 }'
```

providing a list of names of all installed packages only.

It could be converted into JSON format by adding

```bash
| jq --raw-input . | jq --slurp .
```

**Thanks To**

- [Converting lines to JSON in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45603242/6771046)

**Other Q&A**

- [How to list installed packages with their summary using `dnf`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/712553/266568)