# How to list installed packages with their summary using `dnf`?

Tags: package-management, rpm, dnf

I can list installed packages on my Fedora with:

```
dnf list installed
```

When searching for packages, I'd use something like:

```
dnf search terminal
```

`dnf` will proceed to list available packages similar to this:

```
tmux.x86_64 : A terminal multiplexer
```

i.e. "*<package>* : *<summary>*". I'd like to have a similar output of packages, but for *installed* packages. Search among installed packages is not necessary, as I can simply pipe the output into `grep` (or `ripgrep`), but an output like the one that results from a search is something I'd like to have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `rpm` database is already a collection of all your installed packages.

You can query the database directly with `rpm` and extract any available information using the `--queryformat` option without using any additional tools or loops:

```
rpm --query --all --queryformat '%{NAME}.%{ARCH}: %{SUMMARY}\n'
```

Adjust `--queryformat` to use whatever information `rpm` provides:  http://ftp.rpm.org/api/4.4.2.2/queryformat.html

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```bash
for pkg in $(dnf list --installed) ; do
  rpm -q --queryformat '%{NAME} : %{SUMMARY}\n' ${pkg}
done
```

might do the trick (untested, since written on a phone).

The for ... do ... done loop is of course a bit over the top, but it does allow you to do some extra filtering if you want to, log things, surround them in proper HTML, whatever your heart desires

Comment: Right, I'm assuming a command purely reliant on `dnf` isn't possible?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of

Comment: Thanks, that explains a bit. For now I'm using `dnf list --installed | cut -f1 -d' ' | xargs -I '{}' rpm -q --queryformat '{} : %{SUMMARY}\n' '{}'` based on your suggestion. I'll see if someone else comes up with something insightful for a day or two before accepting.

Comment: Since `rpm` already has a database of all the installed packages, should be no need for additional tools or loops: `rpm -qa --queryformat '%{NAME}.%{ARCH}: %{SUMMARY}'`

Comment: @GracefulRestart thanks, please add an answer I can accept.